# Enabling cookie in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, session-state

aspx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btbStart" runat="server"  Text="Click" onclick = "btnClick"/>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie mycook = Request.Cookies["mycookie"];
    if (mycook != null)
      Label1.Text = mycook.Values["test"].ToString();

}

protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("test");
  mycookie.Value = "Hellworld";
  mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4);
  Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);            
}
```

My problem is that I am using IE 9 and the cookie is not enabled. If I use F12 (developer tools) to see the cookie session it is blank.

I use Fiddler and I see the "Set-Cookie" is having the value. But if I open the page in another browser the cookie value is not retrieved. It is blank

I could not understand the problem what is going wrong.

Thanks